# Load remote csv into CHCSVParser

Tags: iphone, csv

I am using Dave DeLong's CHCSVParser to parse a csv. I can parse the csv locally, but I cannot get it load a remote csv file. I have been staring at my MacBook way too long today and the answer is right in front of me.  Here is my code:

```
NSString *urlStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.somewhere.com/LunchSpecials.csv"];
NSURL *lunchFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSStringEncoding encoding = 0;
CHCSVParser *p = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVFile:[lunchFileURL path] usedEncoding:&encoding error:nil];
[p setParserDelegate:self];
[p parse];
[p release];
```

Thanks for any help that someone can give me.

Comment: I can be pretty sure that the man himself will answer your question. Just wait.

Comment: @Jacob sounds like a reasonably safe bet. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-[NSURL path]` is not doing what you're expecting.

If I have the URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636428`, then it's `-path` is `/questions/4636428`.  When you pass that path to CHCSVParser, it's going to try and open that path on the local system.  Since that file doesn't exist, you won't be able to open it.

What you need to do (as Walter points out) is download the CSV file locally, and then open it.  You can download the file in several different ways (`+[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:...]`, `NSURLConnection`, etc).  Once you've got either the file saved locally to disk or the string of CSV in memory, you can then pass it to the parser.

If this is a very big file, then you'll want to `alloc`/`init` a `CHCSVParser` with the path to the local copy of the CSV file.  The parser will then read through it bit by bit and tell you what it finds via the delegate callbacks.

If the CSV file isn't very big, then you can do:

```
NSString * csv = ...; //the NSString containing the contents of the CSV file
NSArray * rows = [csv CSVComponents];
```

That will return an `NSArray` of `NSArrays` of `NSStrings`.

Similar to this last approach is using the `NSArray` category method:

```
NSString * csv = ...;
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * rows = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVString:csv encoding:[csv fastestEncoding] error:&error];
```

This will return the same structure (an `NSArray` of `NSArrays` of `NSStrings`), but it will also provide you with an `NSError` object if it encounters a syntax error in the CSV file (ie, malformed CSV).

Comment: Thanks Dave for your help!  That clears up a lot of questions I had.  By the way, great parser!!  It will come in handy for my app.

Comment: @Dave `CHCSVParser` contains a category on `NSString`? Cool!

Comment: @Jacob Relkin yep, and `NSArray`.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, right. I looked through the entire github repo - it's very nice!

Comment: Hey Dave!  I got the remote csv loaded into my array, but now I have a different problem.  For some reason when adding elements to a spreadsheet in Excel on Windows computer, the parser adds an empty object at the end of the array.  This doesn't happen when I use Excel for Mac.  Do I have to change a setting in the Windows computer?  I did change the Windows computer to encode the csv in UTF8.  Not sure what else to do here.  I am trying to write a piece of code to check to see if the last object in the array is empty.

Comment: @Matt your CSV file probably ends with a newline.  The parser is seeing that and thinking "aha! the start of a new line!" and is informing the delegate about it.  I'll see if I can find a fix for that tonight.

Comment: @Dave Thanks!!  Strange that the Windows version of Excel would add a newline, but the Mac version does not.

Comment: @Matt I just pushed a fix that will exclude empty lines (when using the convenience methods).  If you're using the parser directly, you'll still get a "didStartLine" followed by a "didEndLine"

Comment: @Dave thanks!! I'll implement the new code later tonight and let you know how it goes. Thanks again, your parser works awesome!!

Comment: @Dave  I had to make a small change to your change as it didn't work.  I changed the line to:  if ([currentLine count] > 1)  to see if there was more than one object in the line.  The csv I had was showing a new line, therefore the objects in the new line was greater than 0.  All of my csv will have more than 1 objet in each line so the fix that I added works out. Thanks again for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an NSString, not an NSURL object to pass to the parser so the extra part you are doing with changing the NSString to an NSURL is the issue. Looking at the CHCSVParser documentation, it looks like he wants NSString in the init.

So maybe you could do something like:

```
NSError *err = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *lunchFileURL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somewhere.com/LunchSpecials.csv"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *lunchFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lunchFileURL] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
CHCSVParser *p = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVString:lunchFile usedEncoding:&encoding error:nil];
```

Comment: Correct in principle, wrong in implementation.  Correct in that `CHCSVParser` does not use `NSURL`.  Incorrect in that `NSString` does not have a `-path` method, and also the "`lunchFile`" variable contains the contents of the CSV file, and does not represent a physical file on disk.

Comment: Thans Dave for that. I have updated the example so that it is correct based on your correction suggestions. I went ahead and just kept the string rather than saving the "lunchFile" variable to disk and then reading it back in.