# CHCSVParser - how to load from webserver

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, csv, ios6

I would like to parse csv from webserver which gets updated everyday.I am using the csvparser from this link  https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser and   I am using this code:

```
 NSError *err = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *lunchFileURL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somewhere.com/LunchSpecials.csv"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *lunchFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lunchFileURL] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
CHCSVParser *p = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVString:lunchFile usedEncoding:&encoding error:nil];
```

I get this error  :

```
 No visible @interface for 'CHCSVParser' declares the selector 'initWithContentsOfCSVString:usedEncoding:error:'
```

I checked this link [Load remote csv into CHCSVParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636428/load-remote-csv-into-chcsvparser?rq=1)  and its not working .I am a noob to ios ,Please let me know how to fix this .Really Appreciate the help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks Sachin for the edit.

Comment: FYI, I've updated my answer with two examples. Bottom line, `initWithContentsOfCSVString` is a `NSArray` category method, not a `CHCSVParser` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably be:

```
NSError *err;
NSString *lunchFileURL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somewhere.com/LunchSpecials.csv"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *lunchFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lunchFileURL]
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                  error:&err];

// if you're going to create a CHCSVParser yourself, the syntax is:

CHCSVParser *p = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithCSVString:lunchFile
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                  error:&err];

// or, if you're going to use NSArray+CHCSVAdditions.h, the syntax might be:

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVString:lunchFile
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                        error:&err];
```

Note:

- You don't need to `alloc`/`init` the `NSError` object; these classes that take a `NSError **` parameter will create the autorelease error object for you if they encounter an error; otherwise they leave it alone;
- The `CHCSVParser` class method is not `initWithContentsOfCSVString`, but rather `initWithCSVString`;
- Alternatively, if you use the `NSArray` class extension, then the syntax is `arrayWithContentsOfCSVString` or `initWithContentsOfCSVString`; and
- You specified an encoding of `&encoding`, but this parameter is not a pointer, so I don't see how that can possibly be right; I've just specified the encoding.

I assume you want to use the `NSArray+CHCSVAdditions` category method `initWithContentsOfCSVString` or `arrayWithContentsOfCSVString` (which gives you an `autorelease` object), not the `CHCSVParser`, but it's up to you.

Comment: Best Answer ever.Thank you so much Rob.Awesome!!